# What type of dataset am I working with here in Excel? What word or term can best describe it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, accounting, data-analysis

I am beginning to delve into data analysis via Excel and I would like to learn more about the terminology in terms of some data I'm playing with.

I've created a sample data set for mock invoice charges with different products per invoice listed as unique line items. What type of data set is this called? I want to understand so I can dial in my research and questions moving forward.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you have shown as example is a [table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) (you possibly already know the name). It allows:

> to make managing and analyzing a group of related data easier

Looking at your data, you can manipulate it via [formulae](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188) and/or [pivot tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

> A PivotTable is a powerful tool to calculate, summarize, and analyze data that lets you see comparisons, patterns, and trends in your data

Formulae and Pivot tables will allow to get a better understanding of which clients buy the most (or least), which products they bought, which products sell the most, calculate the sales per month (quarter, year, etc), etc.

You can also use your data to generate pivot charts or create dashboards to show/analyze trends based on items, customers, vendors, etc.

If we take a database approach, your single table can divided into multiple tables. You could have an Invoice table (your example), plus Customers, Vendors and Items tables. You can create a sheet for each of them. Each table will have a primary key -- records must be unique, there must be no duplicates. This is called normalization.

The tables are linked together via foreign keys. A foreign key is a primary key of a table which is also a field in another table. This allows to create relationships between tables.

There are better tools/software for database than Excel. [SQL](https://www.spiceworks.com/tech/artificial-intelligence/articles/what-is-sql/) is used to query your tables when using database software.

There are much more concepts than what I have described. The above are just basic explanations.

**Sources:**

1. [Overview of Excel tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)
2. [Excel functions (alphabetical)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188)
3. [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)
4. [Database basics](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/database-basics-a849ac16-07c7-4a31-9948-3c8c94a7c204#__toc257378512)
5. [What Is SQL? Definition, Elements, Examples, and Uses in 2022](https://www.spiceworks.com/tech/artificial-intelligence/articles/what-is-sql/)

Answer (score 1):

*What you have shared with us is a kind of a dataset the Excel does offers called Table.*

Basically, Excel is a worksheet/spreadsheet, but not a database, the data in Excel is a “Un structured dataset”.

There are many opinions about Excel, some call it a tabular tool, and the best arrangement is a Table. Records in the columns & rows, and the Headers performances as the database field.

Over-all Excel has 3 different ways to dump data, first is spreadsheet where data can be manipulated by using formulas & functions. Another is Tables, and last is the PivotTables with a Tabular Report Layout.

Even though users try to handle it like a database, but has limitations. On other hand is one of the popular tools for data analysis.

Modern days Excel is supported by lots of wonderful features like Power Pivot, Power Query & BI. VBA, LAMDA & Dynamic Array functions enriched the Excel.